# Fresh installation Ubuntu installation failure - Unable to install GRUB on dell server m610 with raid controller h200

Tags: system-installation

I have  installed ubuntu OS 15.10 on dell server m610 with raid controller h200.
OS installation completes but at last step while installing grub it fails
os partion details as below:

> / :lvm partion 100 gb
>
> swap 50 gb
>
> /boot 512 mb

Answer (score 0):

Infra used for Installation :
1)Dell M610 Server with Perc H200 SAS Raid Controller
2)I was Using Raid 1 
3) OS Media Was: Ubuntu 15.10 for i386

Solution :
1) I have deleted the Raid 1 & used Disk 
2) OS media used: Ubuntu 15.10 AMD64